# How do you find or locate just part of the JSON Key name

Tags: arrays, json, json-arrayagg

I am having a hard time getting the JSON Key name. Because the whole name is not fixed. I would like to get the media_id_ but the problem is the numbers next to it is not fixed/static.The goal I am trying achieve here is that I want to get the value of the mediaFit but I can't because I have no idea how to find the media_id_xxx.

```
"media_id_1696320854359": {
  "resourceId": "HzXvCFvKQWrf9hpfMi2u3smsvziXpz2Vazvr",
  "groupId": "9ff31635-b440-41b2-b147-792aed6e5529",
  "orignalId": "HzXvCFvKQWrf9hpfMi2u3smsvziXpz2Vazvr",
  "orignalWidth": 1584,
  "orignalHeight": 1920,
  "horizontal": {
    "height": 1080,
    "width": 891,
    "top": 0,
    "left": 514.5
  },
  "vertical": {},
  "custom": {},
  "type": "img",
  "kenBurns": "forced",
  "mediaFit": "fill",
  "mediaAlign": "center",
  "tags": [],
  "name": "helmet.jpg",
  "height": 1920,
  "width": 1584,
  "modifiedAt": "2023-09-28T14:52:31.214Z",
  "userId": "9ff31635-b440-41b2-b147-792aed6e5529",
}
```

Here is my code. This is pretty messy because I keep checking. Pardon.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(templatePreviewElements.getPreviewSrcUrl().getAttribute("text"));
System.out.println(jsonObject);

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages").getJSONObject(i);
  for (Object key: jsonObject2.keySet()) {
    //based on you key types
    String keyStr = (String)key;
    Object keyvalue = jsonObject2.get(keyStr);
    //Print key and value
    System.out.println("key: " + keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

    if (keyStr.contains("media_id")) {
      String actualEffect = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages")
        .getJSONObject(i)
        .getJSONObject("media_id")
        .getString("mediaFit");
      System.out.println("Actual Selected Text Effect: " + actualEffect);
      System.out.println("Expected Selected Text Effect: " + mediaEffect);
      assertEquals(actualEffect, mediaEffect);
      System.out.println(keyStr.contains("media_id"));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have found a way to identifiy the correct propertyname already, but you don't use that propertyname

```
if (keyStr.contains("media_id")) {
  String actualEffect = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages")
    .getJSONObject(i)
    .getJSONObject("media_id")  //this will retrieve an object with the key "media_id", which doesn't exist
    .getString("mediaFit");
   ...
}
```

You of course must use `keyString` here instead of `"media_id"` to get the correct object

```
if (keyStr.contains("media_id")) {
  String actualEffect = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pages")
    .getJSONObject(i)
    .getJSONObject(keyStr)
    .getString("mediaFit");
   ...
}
```

Furthermore, you already have isolated the correct wrapper object (ie `jsonObject2`) and even the correct mediaIdObject (ie `keyvalue`) here. So there is no need you start from scratch again, ie you can just do

```
if (keyStr.contains("media_id")) {
  String actualEffect = ((JSONObject)keyvalue).getString("mediaFit");
   ...
}
```

here, if the key fits the condition.

Comment: you're a savior! Thank you so much!!!